# Shortest path distance from source(s) to all nodes in the graph - O(m + n log(n)) time

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra, bellman-ford

Let G(V,E) be a directed weighted graph with edge lengths, where all of the edge lengths are positive except two of the edges have negative lengths. Given a fixed vertex s, give an algorithm computing shortest paths from s to any other vertex in O(e + v log(v)) time.

My work:

I am thinking about using the reweighting technique of Johnson's algorithm. And then, run Belford Algo once and apply Dijkstra v times. This will give me the time complexity as O(v^2 log v + ve).
This is the standard all pair shortest problem, As I only need one vertex (s) - my time complexity will be O(v log v + e) right?

Comment: Please do not vandalize posts. I fail to see how any of your edits significantly improved your question, and the last two rendered it useless to future visitors. I've rolled the post back to its original revision and removed my downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of problem, changing the graph is often a lot easier than changing the algorithm. Let's call the two negative-weight edges N1 and N2; a path by definition cannot use the same edge more than once, so there are four kinds of path:

- A. Those which use neither N1 nor N2,
- B. Those which use N1 but not N2,
- C. Those which use N2 but not N1,
- D. Those which use both N1 and N2.

So we can construct a new graph with four copies of each node from the original graph, such that for each node `u` in the original graph, `(u, A)`, `(u, B)`, `(u, C)` and `(u, D)` are nodes in the new graph. The edges in the new graph are as follows:

- For each positive weight edge `u-v` in the original graph, there are four copies of this edge in the new graph, `(u, A)-(v, A)` ... `(u, D)-(v, D)`. Each edge in the new graph has the same weight as the corresponding edge in the original graph.
- For the first negative-weight edge (N1), there are two copies of this edge in the new graph; one from layer A to layer B, and one from layer C to layer D. These new edges have weight 0.
- For the second negative-weight edge (N2), there are two copies of this edge in the new graph; one from layer A to layer C, and one from layer B to layer D. These new edges have weight 0.

Now we can run any standard single-source shortest-path problem, e.g. Dijkstra's algorithm, just once on the new graph. The shortest path from the source to a node `u` in the original graph will be one of the following four paths in the new graph, whichever corresponds to a path of the lowest weight in the original graph:

- `(source, A)` to `(u, A)` with the same weight.
- `(source, A)` to `(u, B)` with the weight in the new graph minus the weight of N1.
- `(source, A)` to `(u, C)` with the weight in the new graph minus the weight of N2.
- `(source, A)` to `(u, D)` with the weight in the new graph minus the weights of N1 and N2.

Since the new graph has 4V vertices and 4E - 2 edges, the worst-case performance of Dijkstra's algorithm is `O((4E - 2) + 4V log 4V)`, which simplifies to `O(E + V log V)` as required.

To ensure that a shortest path in the new graph corresponds to a genuine path in the original graph, it remains to be proved that a path from e.g. `(source, A)` to `(u, B)` will not use two copies of the same edge from the original graph. That is quite easy to show, but I'll leave it to you as something to think about.

Comment: It's not clear exactly how you want the algorithm to work, but at least it is straightforward to show that it doesn't meet the time complexity requirement. If you're running Dijkstra's algorithm V times then the complexity of that is O(VE + V^2 log V), so that is the time it takes to do what you said your algorithm should do. The output of that is all-pairs shortest paths and you only need single-source shortest paths, but you can't divide the time complexity by V simply because you only need part of the output; ignoring the rest of the output doesn't make the algorithm faster.

Comment: For an analogy, if you have a list of numbers of length N, then you can count the frequency of all distinct elements into a dictionary in O(N) time, but that doesn't mean given the same list that you can count the frequency of one specific element in O(1) time.

Comment: The O(VE) cost for Bellman-Ford is already "above" the allowed time complexity for any graph with more than O(log V) edges, i.e. almost all graphs. I would need a more detailed description of your algorithm to be able to say whether it can correctly solve the problem, but I can say that it doesn't meet the time complexity requirement. If you're interested in just the correctness specifically, I'd suggest trying to implement your algorithm in code and testing it first; if your testing doesn't convince you either way, then you could ask a new question here (and your code would help a lot).